# Consuming WCF with Xamarin form, completed args is null

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, xamarin

I'm trying to consume a WCF Service in my xamarin forms app but I think I've a problem with my CompletedEventArgs because I've got a  null object reference error (in the catch).
Here's my code :

```
    private void callWCF()
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceRandom req = new ServiceRandom ();
            req.InsertUserDetailsCompleted += req_InsertCompleted;
            ProspectDetails prospectDetails = new ProspectDetails();
            prospectDetails.Nom = "Test insertion appl";
            req.InsertUserDetailsAsync(prospectDetails); 

            Test.Text = "ok";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Test.Text = ex.Message;
        }



    }

    private void req_InsertCompleted(object sender, InsertUserDetailsCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        string str = args.Result; 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: if you're getting a null ref exception in the catch, then that has nothing to do with your Completed args.  You need to use the debugger to figure out exactly which object is null.  My guess would be "Test"

Comment: thank you actually i've an inner exception "endpoint service exception", currently working on it